# Acceptance rejection method for a binomial distribution

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution, simulation, beta-distribution

I have a R-code for acceptance rejection method for a beta-distribution but would like to use it for a binomial(30, 0.4) distribution instead. Here is the code:

```
sample.x = runif(100000,0,1)
accept = c()

for(i in 1:length(sample.x)){
 U = runif(1, 0, 1)
 if(dunif(sample.x[i], 0, 1)*3*U <= dbeta(sample.x[i], 6, 3)) {
   accept[i] = 'Yes'
 }
 else if(dunif(sample.x[i],0,1)*3*U > dbeta(sample.x[i], 6, 3)) {
  accept[i] = 'No'
 }
}
```

Is it possible to modify it so that it works for my binomial distribution instead?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

I am trying to implement Glen's answer to my question, but I cannot get it to work as I want. Does anyone have a solution? Here is my new R-code:

```
sample.x = runif(10000,0,1)
accept = c()

for(i in 1:length(sample.x)){
 U = runif(1, 0, 1600)
 if(dunif(1, 0, 1)*1600*U <= dbinom(1, 30, 0.4)) {
   accept[i] = 'Yes'
 }
 else if(dunif(1,0,1)*1600*U > dbinom(1, 30, 0.4)) {
  accept[i] = 'No'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to generate binomials using accept-reject, but if you're not careful, it can be very inefficient.

One important thing to note is that beta distributions are continuous while binomials are discrete.

This means that the distribution you apply accept-reject to should be discrete (though that might itself be obtained by discretizing a continuous distribution).

An example binomial pmf (black) and a majorizing scaled uniform (grey):

[image]

The accept-reject algorithm is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Algorithm); in this case $g(x)$ is discrete.

The same basic ideas apply - you generate from a discrete distribution ($g(x)$; in the simplest case a discrete uniform, though beware the efficiency issue), you generate a second (this time continuous) uniform on the scaled up probability function ($U[0,Mg(x)]$) to compare with the target probability function ($f(x)$), accepting the generated value if the uniform is below it.

Comment: Hi Glen! Thanks for the fast answer. Do you know how to apply this in the r-code that I pasted i my question? Thanks!

Comment: I do. But I'm not going to write your code for you. Nobody in their right mind would do this in practice, implying you're doing it for a class or similar study (formal or informal). In which case - even if writing the R code was on-topic - it would fall under the restrictions of the `self-study` tag - see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Some hints, however: a discrete uniform is perhaps most easily generated via `sample` (or `sample.int`) with the `replace` argument set to `TRUE`, and for the binomial probability function see `?dbinom`.

Comment: I should clarify - nobody would use the discrete uniform in practice for generating the general binomial case (it's really only suitable for some limited situations. There might be a broader set of cases where a different $g$ would be tenable in practice.